# How to know in which pixels of a image user clicked?

Tags: android

I want to draw a image filling the complete screen.
Then when user clicks in any pixel or group of pixels they turn black.
How can I know where the user clicked exactly and how can I turn the touched pixels black?

Comment: does android have a FloodFill function?

Comment: I don't think so, but that is not what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably draw a canvas over the image. Check out onTouchEvent and [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and have a look at this "paint" demo: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html